# log the ballerina log to a separate file programmatically

Tags: logging, wso2, ballerina

I need to log requests and responses in my ballerina program to a separate file, without logging them in the console. Need to do this programmatically without executing console commands like redirecting the log to a separate file. Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no straight way to log requests and responses to a log file unless you write your own logger in ballerina. You can write an interceptor(https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-filters.html) which logs the requests and responses to a log file.

Alternatively, you can log the http trace logs to a file instead of the console using the console commands. Use `b7a.http.tracelog.path` to give a file path instead of using `b7a.http.tracelog.console`.

Example:
`ballerina run -e b7a.http.tracelog.path=trace-logs.log hello_world_k8s.bal`